# Ec2 host multiple pages, server ignore virtualhost

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

im new to amazon web services.

I have installed an ec2 instance with lamp, everything seems to be OK.

I manage the server through ssh,

I've created the 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/jak-udelat-cz.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@jak-udelat.cz
ServerName www.jak-udelat.cz
ServerAlias jak-udelat.cz

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/jak-udelat.cz

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/jak-udelat.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/jak-udelat2.log  combined
```

Then I restarted the apache..

But when I run

```
sudo a2ensite jak-udelat.cz
```

, i get

```
ERROR: Site jak-udelat.cz does not exist!
```

The domain www.jak-udelat.cz is going on the server right, php works, mysql works, everything seems to be ok, instead of this...

Could you please point me out where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conf file is named `jak-udelat-cz.conf`, so you should do:

```
sudo a2ensite jak-udelat-cz
```

Comment: sudo a2ensite jak-udelat-cz

Enabling site jak-udelat-cz.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 reload

So I did, then I went to www.jak-udelat.cz and it displays the same :/ it should show content on www.jak-udelat.cz/jak-udelat.cz/, but thank you for this advice :) It was very helpful and I didnt know that

Answer (score 0):

OK :D so, I changed almost everything like without seeing any change, so I absolutely out of mind tried reboot, then once more restart apache and it finally helped! :)